# jquery redirect url with url rewrite behavior

Tags: jquery, .htaccess

In my site I use url rewrite but I have a problem when I make a redirect using js

```
<div class="bttn redirect" data-url="bar/">GO</div>

$('.bttn.redirect').on('click', function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    if (typeof url === 'undefined' || url === null || url === "") {
        url = '.';
    }
    //window.location.href = url;  <-- Add bar/ to original
    //window.location.replace(url); <-- Add bar/ to original
    //document.location.href = 'url'; <-- Add bar/ to original
    //location.replace(url); <-- Add bar/ to original
});

--> original url = mydomain.com/foo/
--> redirected url = mydomain.com/foo/bar/
```

Instead if I use html href everything works fine

```
<a href="href="bar/">GO</a>

--> original url = mydomain.com/foo/
--> redirected url = mydomain.com/bar/
```

.htaccess

```
..
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?act=$1&vid=$2 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?act=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How can I solve? Thank you